# How can i bind C-x-insert in emacs

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, elisp

I want to bind C-x-insert to a command. This works:

```
(global-set-key [\C-insert] 'my-func)
```

But this doesn't:

```
(global-set-key [\C-x-insert] 'my-func)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>insert</kbd> tells me

`C-x <insert> is undefined`

Which tells me how Emacs refers to that sequence, which in turn means that I can pass the string `"C-x <insert>"` into the `kbd` function, and it will Just Work.

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x <insert>") 'my-func)
```

`kbd` is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
(define-key ctl-x-map [insert] 'beginning-of-line)
```